# Magento 1.8.1 Shopper 'My Account' menu for mobile version

Tags: magento-1.8, customer-account, menu, mobile

I would like to know if anyone knows how can I make the "My account" menu section (of the shopper page) responsive in Mobile version?
Such as I have tabs block per line like "Account Dashboard", "Account Information", "Address Book", "My Orders", etc... in which whenever I click on any of those tabs blocks it discloses the contents and when I click it again it hides the content.

I guess I have to modify those following files:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml

```
<div class="block block-account">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Account'); ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul>
            <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
            <?php $_index = 1; ?>
            <?php $_count = count($_links); ?>
            <?php foreach ($_links as $_link): ?>
                <?php $_last = ($_index++ >= $_count); ?>
                <?php if ($this->isActive($_link)): ?>
                    <li class="current<?php echo ($_last ? ' last' : '') ?>"><strong><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></strong></li>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <li<?php echo ($_last ? ' class="last"' : '') ?>><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

> app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Navigation.php

```
class Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected $_links = array();
    protected $_activeLink = false;
    public function addLink($name, $path, $label, $urlParams=array())
    {
        $this->_links[$name] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'name' => $name,
            'path' => $path,
            'label' => $label,
            'url' => $this->getUrl($path, $urlParams),
        ));
        return $this;
    }
    public function setActive($path)
    {
        $this->_activeLink = $this->_completePath($path);
        return $this;
    }
    public function getLinks()
    {
        return $this->_links;
    }
    public function isActive($link)
    {
        if (empty($this->_activeLink)) {
            $this->_activeLink = $this->getAction()->getFullActionName('/');
        }
        if ($this->_completePath($link->getPath()) == $this->_activeLink) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    protected function _completePath($path)
    {
        $path = rtrim($path, '/');
        switch (sizeof(explode('/', $path))) {
            case 1:
                $path .= '/index';
                // no break

            case 2:
                $path .= '/index';
        }
        return $path;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help/responses.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using css to do this? Look for the css files in `skin/frontend/default/default/css` or the css files of whatever theme you are using and google the use of `@media` to create different styles dependent on the screen size of the device being used.

Comment: Css will help me to re-size or change the position of some fields. What I am looking for is having a Menu tab so that when you click on "Account Information" the relevant information will be displayed below that section and when i click back it will hide this section.